# Transfer from smart contracts?

Tags: smart-contracts

Can smart contract account (address starting with KT1) transfer Tezos to other accounts?  I know this is possible for plain vanilla KT1 account.

Answer (score 3):

This Arthur's answer from Slack:

> Depends. If they are marked as "spendable" they can, or if they have some internal logic that allows that transfer to happen
>
> Spendable was deprecated in Athens and is fully replaced in Babylon with internal logic.

https://tezos-baking.slack.com/archives/CC4FD2HUY/p1569757418006400